# Code works in PHP script but get 500 error when put into CodeIgniter. AWS PHP SDK 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, codeigniter-2, image-uploading

I had this code in a script and it ran just as intended but then when I put into a basic CodeIgniter Model to run it I get a 500 error. I have narrowed it down to the "use Aws\S3\S3Client" and all of the lines that use the "use" function. I am very unfamiliar with namespaces and am not sure where to start here. Here is the code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dev_model extends CI_Model {

    public function aws()
    {
        require_once('AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar');

        use Aws\S3\S3Client;
        use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
        use Aws\Common\Aws;
        use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
        use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
        use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

        //get the $s3 object
        $config = array(
            'key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'region' => Region::US_EAST_1    
        );
        $s3 = S3Client::factory($config);

        try {
            $test = file_get_contents("http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg");
            $result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => 'mybucket',
                'Key'        => "picture.jpg",
                'Body' => $test
            ));
            echo 'complete';
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Do you know how to view the error logs in CodeIgniter? I am having trouble finding them! @MeisamMulla

Comment: I meant the httpd error logs.

Comment: application/logs folder for CodeIgniter error log

Comment: did you get any solution? I have a similar problem when using aws.phar from the Restler framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605125/aws-php-sdk-2-aws-phar-does-not-work-with-restler-framework

Comment: No @alvarolb sorry, I ended up using the AWS Rest API instead of their SDK. The REST API is much simpler but it only allows S3 and cloud front interaction which is limiting if you want to use other AWS products.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem with the autoloader, i encountered a simmilar problem with restler where  spl_auload_unregister was called by the framework.

You should also try using the absolute names by prefixing with \, like "use \Aws\S3\S3Client"